# How to change an Alert to a Modal using SweetAlert2

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, sweetalert2

I am trying to change an Alert to a Modal, I have a function in Typescript to subscribe an user for example when the subscriber is ok, I can call a Modal of success, but I have another alert in this function if the subscribe not works, my question is, how can I change the second alert (which does not work the subscribe) from my function to a Modal of error? I mean, I want to put two different Modals for the same function.

I've tried to make a function in JavaScript, using Sweetalert2 and using with Angular, but both it didn't work, also something like this:

```
<swal #ok
type="success"
title="Cadastro realizado comsucesso!"  (confirm)="CadastrarUsuario()">
</swal>

<swal #ok
type="error"
title="Cadastro não realizado!" (confirm)="CadastrarUsuario()">
</swal>

<button type="submit" [swal]="ok" class="btn btn-primary def-button">Cadastrar Usuário</button>
```

### This is my function:

#### cadastro-user.component.ts

```
CadastrarUsuario() {

if (this.roleVisivel == 1) {

  this.lider.perfil = "LiderTecnico";
  this.funcionarioService.cadastrarFuncionarioPorAdmin(this.lider).subscribe (
    data => {
      // alert("CADASTRADO COM SUCESSO !")
      location.reload();
    },
    error => {
      alert("Algo de errado nao esta certo.")
    }
  );


  } else if (this.roleVisivel == 2) {
    this.user.admin = true;
    this.usuariosService.cadastrarGerente(this.user).subscribe (
      data => {
        // alert("CADASTRADO COM SUCESSO !")
        location.reload();
      },
      error => {
        alert("Algo de errado nao esta certo.")
      }
    );

}
```

}

#### cadastro-user.component.html

```
<swal #ok
type="success"
title="Cadastro realizado comsucesso!"  (confirm)="CadastrarUsuario()">
</swal>

<button type="submit" [swal]="ok" class="btn btn-primary def-button">Cadastrar Usuário</button>
```